# Find in which folders changes took place on commit to Github

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

For our project we are working with a continuous integration pipeline using Github actions. Due to restrictions we have all our applications separated into directories within one single Git repository. For our CD pipeline we would like to only run the tests in folders that were changed, not on folders in which no changes took place. How would we achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'documentation/**'
    branches:
      - master
```

This example triggers a workflow only on the master branch, and when a file changes in the documentation folder. You can then write a separate workflow for every subproject.